# Esprimere una domanda e la sua risposta in modo indiretto

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

È corretto usare "alla domanda di ..." per esprimere in modo indiretto una domanda seguita dalla risposta? Per esempio,

> Alla domanda di dove avesse (abbia?) trovato il coraggio, il pescatore ha ammesso che tutto il merito era dell'alcool che aveva bevuto.

Comment: *Alla domanda su…*

Comment: Io apporterei ancora un'altra piccola variazione:
"alla domanda su dove avesse trovato il coraggio, il pescatore ammise che tutto il merito fosse dell'alcool che aveva bevuto."

Comment: Conflitto tra “prescrizione grammaticale” e uso: dubito che userei il congiuntivo *fosse* in casi del genere. Ma, prima di tutto, benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A me suona un po' strano. Userei piuttosto "su", o ancora meglio una locuzione tipo "relativa a" o "riguardante", ma queste ultime suonano un po' accademiche - dipende dal contesto.

Riformulerei così:

"Alla domanda su dove avesse trovato il coraggio, il pescatore ammise che tutto il merito era dell'alcool che aveva bevuto."